# Assistance with SQL View

Tags: sql, oracle, view, plsql, ora-00911

I'm having a little trouble with this sql view.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_themed_booking AS 
SELECT tb.*,         
       CASE 
         WHEN (tb.themed_party_size % 2) = 0 THEN 
           (tb.themed_party_size-2)/2
         ELSE ((tb.themed_party_size-2)/2) + 0.5
       END themed_tables
  FROM themed_booking tb;
```

Can anyone help me here? I'm trying to add a column to the end of the view that the natural number result of `(S-2)/2` where `S` is the `themed_party_size`.

When i say natural number result i mean like round up the answers that end in .5 so if `S=7` the answer would be `3` and not `2.5`.

The error I get when I try and run the above code is

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_themed_booking AS 
SELECT tb.*,         
  CASE WHEN (tb.themed_party_size % 2) = 0
    THEN (tb.themed_party_size-2)/2
    ELSE ((tb.themed_party_size-2)/2) + 0.5
  END themed_tables
FROM themed_booking tb
Error at Command Line:3 Column:34
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
*Action:
```

If it makes a difference I am using sqldeveloper connected to an oracle server so I can use PL/SQL.

Comment: haha oh sorry forgot to add the error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simplify with the `CEIL()` or `ROUND()` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_themed_booking AS 
SELECT tb.*,         
       ROUND((tb.themed_party_size-2)/2) AS themed_tables
  FROM themed_booking tb;
```

Not sure why you get that error. Perhaps it's the `%` operator that is not available in Oracle. This links suggests so: [Fundamentals of PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/02_funds.htm). There seems to be a `MOD()` function though.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is telling you what the problem is.
Look at Line:3 Column:34
It is an invalid character

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_themed_booking AS 
SELECT tb.*,         
  CASE WHEN (tb.themed_party_size % 2) = 0
                                  ^
```

My suspicion is that you are trying to use the modulo operator.
Since you are using oracle PL/SQL, you should use `mod`

Here is a reference [Oracle/PLSQL: Mod Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/mod.php)